# Spell checker mechanism in Database

Tags: sql, database, spell-checking

Like in front end applications, it shows the red line under text which means text spelling is incorrect. Similar to this do we have any function or method in which we can identify and correct wrong spellings in Database ? Databases like: MSSQL, Oracle or SAS.

`HAVE                             |    WANT
----------------------------------|---------------------------------
dis is windows based app          | this is window based application
thsi phn has some many aplication | this phone has some many applications`

Comment: No.  This seems very much like a front-end application thing.

Comment: SQL itself has no spell-checking functionality.

Comment: thanks, I just wanted to clear my doubt.